# Trigger alert when prometheus metric goes from "doesn't exist" to "exists"

Tags: prometheus

I'd like to configure a prometheus alert to trigger when an existing metric shows up with new label values.

Example: a metric named `my_metric` has a label named `sv`. When `my_metric{sv="john"}` goes from "doesn't exist" to "exists" or "has value", it would trigger the alarm. However, I don't know in advance what the new value "john" will be.

Is this possible? What would the expression look like?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the query looks like this:

```
my_metric unless my_metric offset 10m
```

Simply put, the above gives you all `my_metric` time series, except those that were present `10m` ago:

- `unless` removes from the output time series with equal label sets;
- `offset 10m` changes the evaluation time for the last `my_metric` from 'now' to `10m` ago. In the context of your task, this would also define how long the alert will be firing before going resolved automatically.

Example:

```
# my_metric 10 minutes ago
my_metric{foo="bar"} 1.0

# my_metric now
my_metric{foo="bar"} 1.0
my_metric{foo="baz"} 1.0

# query result:
my_metric{foo="baz"} 1.0
```

Now, in the basic form above you will receive an alert for any new label set. If you want to watch for appearance of some specific labels, then add some aggregation:

```
avg by(label1, label2) (my_metric) unless avg by(label1, label2) (my_metric) offset 10m
```

Replace `label1, label2` ***on both sides*** with label names that make sense in your case. You can also use other aggregation functions (`min()`, `max()`, `sum()`, etc) instead of `avg()`.