# How to determine a windows process has restarted using PromQL and Grafana

Tags: windows, prometheus, grafana

I am using the 'windows_exporter' metric exporter on a windows server...I am trying to use the metric from that called "windows_process_start_time" to visualize how many times a process has restarted based on the process and process_id.

this is my promQL used within the Grafana dashboard

```
changes( windows_process_start_time { process="Foo.*", process_id=~".*"[$__interval] )
```

however, when a process has stopped, and a new one starts with a new process_id, the 'changes' is no detecting it, so in the grafana dashboard it still shows 0 for a 'Foo' Processor.

What would be an effective PromQL do show when a process restarts?

updated with suggested solution in comment, but this does not work:

```
avg by (windows_process_start_time { process="Foo.*", process_id=~".*"}) unless avg by (process,process_d) ( windows_process_start_time { process="Foo.*", process_id=~".*"} )
```

Comment: `changes()` does not count the appearance of a metric as a change, it only cares about value changes in existing time series. If you wish to alert when a new time series appears (=when a new process starts), I have an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70351617/trigger-alert-when-prometheus-metric-goes-from-doesnt-exist-to-exists/70352629#70352629

Comment: I am tryin to show how many times a process restarted using prometheus and grafana...reviewin the answer in the link doesn't seem to work...here is what i have in granfana(uses Prometheus as data source.) based on the link you shared. *updated question with suggested answer*