# Prometheus Alert Manager - alert on every exception

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have an API which has a very low QPS, but I need to be alerted whenever there is an exception in any of the calls.

My alert manager config (excerpt) is as below. I have no `for` clause.

```
- alert: internal_private_api_alert_errors
expr: (sum(increase(internal_api_exceptions_total{identifier=~'private_api'}[1m]))) > 0
labels:
  notify: admin
  severity: warning
```

However this doesn't seem to work. If an exception occurs at 1PM, I don't get alerted. If it occurs again at 3PM, I still don't get it.

My grafana just seems to register a flat line at `0` whenever any exception occurs.

The grafana query is the same thing: `(sum(increase(internal_api_exceptions_total{identifier=~'private_api'}[1m])))`

[image]

I seem to get alerted if the exception occurs at 1PM, then again at 1:01PM, but basically I cannot rely on this since exceptions are sporadic

Is my query wrong?

I am using a prometheus Counter

Comment: This might be the case when the metric just appears, in such case `increase()` won't fire until the metrics gets a second increase. As you see on the graph, the value comes from Null to 0, to calculate delta, you need at least two values (two exceptions, that is). Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70351617/trigger-alert-when-prometheus-metric-goes-from-doesnt-exist-to-exists/70352629#70352629 . Also, I suggest you consider using https://sentry.io for the task.

Comment: @anemyte thanks. So in my case, would I add `(sum(increase(internal_api_exceptions_total{identifier=~'private_api'}[1m]))) unless (sum(increase(internal_api_exceptions_total{identifier=~'private_api'}[1m]))) offset 1m`?

Comment: Nope, not there yet. First you need to cover the case when the amount of exceptions increases, your old query will do just fine. Then you need to cover that special case with `increase()` not working. Thus, `(your old query) or (internal_api_exceptions_total{identifier=~'private_api'} unless internal_api_exceptions_total{identifier=~'private_api'} offset 1m)`. Don't use sum in the second part.

Comment: @anemyte so I did `(sum(increase(internal_api_exceptions_total{identifier=~'private_api'}[1m]))) > 0) or (internal_api_exceptions_total{identifier=~'private_api'} unless internal_api_exceptions_total{identifier=~'private_api'} offset 1m)` , and I see the line in grafana every time an exception occurs, however I am not being notified via slack. Does the exception have to keep occuring for me to get alerted? How can this be fixed to alert me at every exception?

Comment: The query seems fine now, except that it only fires for 1 minute. Your alerting configuration might not send anything because it resolves so soon. Change `increase()` interval to something larger and make `offset 5m` or more. Once again, I thing you should really consider using Sentry for this. The tool was made for the task that you're trying to hack with Prometheus.

Comment: @anemyte I am using sentry. How it works is, when an exception occurs, it is logged to sentry. Also, a prometheus alert should be fired to notify me that exception occured, so I go and check sentry. I dont think sentry can automatically notify you when something occured

Comment: Sentry has alerts https://docs.sentry.io/product/alerts/ and with 'custom metric' rule you can make it to fire if number of errors in 1 minute exceeds  0. Not sure it can send you a slack message, but an email - for sure. You can then create a email for your account in slack and feed it to sentry to receive notifications in slack.

Comment: The best way with Prometheus would be to initialize your metric `internal_api_exceptions_total` on the application start with 0. This would give you the first sample. When error would happen, the metric will get increased - and you'll get the second sample. With two samples, `increase` will begin to work. Please also ensure, that your interval of `1m` is at least 4x times bigger than Prometheus `scrape_interval`. When `[interval]` is too small, Prometheus is unable to locate two datapoints for comparing and returns nothing.